# Targeting parent objects with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I must be losing my mind since something so simple is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/vB7Nd/

I'm trying to add up cost of items in a loop through a list and append the price to the title tag in the header, but I can't seem to target it:

### HTML structure:

```
<div id="holder"> 
<div class="container">    
<span class="title1" style="border: 1px solid green;">Total:</span>   
<ul>
<li cost="2" type="clothes">Car</li>
<li cost="5" type="clothes">Hat</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="container">    
<span class="title1" style="border: 1px solid green;">Total:</span>   
<ul>
<li cost="4" type="product">Coffee</li>
<li cost="4" type="product">Milk</li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

### JS

```
    $('#holder ul').each(function(index, value) { 
    var cost = 0;
    $(this).children().each(function(index,value) {

    var classification = $(this).attr('type'); 
    switch(classification) {

    case 'clothes':
    console.log(parseInt($(this).attr('cost')));
    cost +=  parseInt($(this).attr('cost')); 
    //this line does not work:
    $(this).parents('.container').closest('title1').css('border','1px solid red');
     //neither does this:
    $(this).parent().parent().find('title1').append(cost);
    break;
    }
    });

    console.log('cost is' +cost);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see it can be as simple as

```
$('#holder .container').each(function (index, value) {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).find('li').each(function () {
        total += +$(this).attr('cost') || 0;
    })
    $(this).find('.title1').append(total)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7E2VU/)

Note: I have used the unary plus operator to convert the string value of cost to a number instead of using `parseInt()`

Comment: `this.getAttribute("cost")` would also work, and you should also mention the `+` in front is to cast as a `Number`

Comment: @RUJordan added a note

Answer (score 0):

You are missing class selector in find.use:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('.title1').append(cost);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vB7Nd/2/)**